# Automator "Add to Album" error

Tags: high-sierra, automator, photos.app

This Automator workflow worked in Sierra, but it fails in High Sierra with the error, "The chosen receiving album does not exist in the Photos library: ".  The album does exist, and the dropdown list shows all my existing albums.  In the error message, there is no text after the colon, so it seems to be trying to add to blank-named album.

[image]

Comment: Can you add files to other albums, or does attempting to do so also result in errors? If it's not a consistent problem across destinations, then try renaming the "From Lightroom" album so that it does not contain a space, such as "FromLightroom" or "From_Lightroom". (And re-configure the workflow to match the change, of course.)

Comment: It happens with all albums, including if I tell it to create a new album.

Comment: Have you recompiled the script in High Sierra? Sometimes this is needed for at least some scripts to work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a use case for the "Import Files into Photos" action if the images are coming from outside of Photos.